# Did you go (somewhere/anywhere) exciting at the weekend?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I thought the right answer was using "anywhere" because that what we use in negative sentences and questions but it turned out that it is "somewhere exciting" not "anywhere exciting"! The question is why?

1. Did you go somewhere exciting at the weekend?
2. Did you go anywhere exciting at the weekend?

What if the answer to the question is negative. How would you say that?

> I did not go "anywhere exciting" at the weekend.

Comment: I think both sentences are possible but have slightly different meaning.

Comment: By the way, your profile says that you speak and are especially interested in North American English.  We don't usually say *at the weekend* in American English; I think it's used mainly in British English.  In this particular case, I'd say *over the weekend*, personally.

Comment: Won't it be *the last weekend* since it's *did*?

Comment: Some v Any - http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/some-v-any/. Nevertheless, I prefer *Did you go to any/some exciting place last weekend?* with the answer *No, I didn't.*

Comment: I have not checked @MaulikV 's answer but I think I have found the answer [here](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic25477.html)

Comment: @snailboat Yes I am interested in AmE more than BrE but I come across both. I am also aware of many differences between both, but I know is nothing to what I don't, that is why I welcome your input

Comment: @learner Hmm...  I think you could get better answers than those.  I disagree with Torsten's claim that "you probably expect a negative answer" with *anywhere*, and I disagree with Haihao's implication that *somewhere* implies a yes-or-no question.

Comment: Then could you tell me the slightly different meaning between the two please. Meanwhile I will look into the differences in Swan's book, PEU. I think I found something that supports Torsten's claim, but I am not sure yet, I have to read first.

Comment: From Swan's Practical English Usage section 547, p.540 3rd edition.
**Some in questions**
We use *some* in questions if we expect people to answer ‘Yes’, or want to encourage them to say ‘Yes’ – for example requests and offers.
[*Have you brought **some** paper and a pen?*]
(The hearer is expected to bring them.)
*Shouldn’t there be **some** instructions with it?*
*Would you like **some** more meat?*
*Could I have **some** brown rice, please?*
*Have you got **some** glasses that I could borrow?*

Comment: I copied Swan's discussion about some because he stated that the differences between **some-** and **any-** are the same as for **some** and **any**. You can find this on p.540 section 548 part 2 (some- and any-): "The differences between somebody and anybody, something and anything, somewhere and anywhere etc are the same as the differences between some and any (see 547 for details). Compare : (...) If you need **something/anything** just shout. - Let's go **somewhere** nice for dinner. I don't want to go **anywhere** too expensive."

Comment: @learner *Any* is associated with a lack of assertion, not a negative assertion.

Comment: [Here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2662246) is an opinion that supports your claim @snailboat . Could you give a scenario that explains your last comment about lack of assertion please. In ten minutes I will be going to work so I may check the comments later.

Comment: @learner Swan appears to agree with my comment.  See page 539: "*Any* (used in this sense) is a 'non-affirmative' word (see 381) ..." And item 381 (on page 355) is titled "non-affirmative (or 'non-assertive') words".  The term "non-assertive" refers to a lack of assertion, not to a negative assertion.

Comment: This is one of the questions that I found reading the comments is really useful. @snailboat, maybe you could wrap your comments and exchanges with learner as the answer?

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'd prefer not to write an answer because a proper description of *some* versus *any* would be quite long, and it's more work than I want to put into an answer right now.  Also, I must admit that I'm put off by [learner's request](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/3156/learner) not to have answers written by non-native speakers--perhaps because I myself am a non-native speaker (of languages other than English).

Comment: That request of mine was because of a bad experience with a non-native speaker who voted down a question of mine when I first started posting questions. What was worse is that he couldn't answer the question nor did he give a correct comment. It was incomplete and in that context misleading. However, you have been told that your input is welcome. As for me I've never answered anyone's questions on this website even when I am able to. Anyway, I will remove that request.

Comment: @snailboat  I strongly encourage you to put at least what you have in comments as an answer.  While the request may encourage answers from native speakers, that's only because native speakers generally have a better grasp than learners.  That said, you (and DamkerngT.) seem to have a good grasp and certainly in this case your answer is correct.  Exorbitant detail is not necessary - especially since you have sources you can link to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sentences are perfectly correct. They have a slightly different connotation however.

> "Did you go somewhere exciting at the weekend?"

The *somewhere* in this sentence suggests to me that you are certain that they went out, but you are asking if the place to which they went was exciting.

You might use this form if the person usually went places, or perhaps they are sunburned or look hungover or some other thing that you're sure they didn't just stay at home.

> "Did you go anywhere exciting at the weekend?"

The *anywhere* in this sentence suggests to me that you are uncertain about both whether they went out at all, and whether it was exciting if they did go out.

Note: I am a speaker of British English so there may be other subtle difference to a US speaker of which I am unaware. Additionally, I have seen "at the weekend" used quite a lot in English textbooks for non-English speakers, but I would say that "on the weekend", "over the weekend" or "last weekend" are probably the more common ways to say it for a native speaker.

Comment: Thanks @Big Luke Could you please confirm that "on the weekend" is more common than "at the weekend" in British English? If so, is that because of AmE influence I've read about it in Swan's and on the Internet?

Comment: @learner In the [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://corpus2.byu.edu/bnc/), I find 705 results for *at the weekend* and only 75 results for *on the weekend*.

Comment: Thanks for the corpora @snailboat You may want to know that you hooked me into using [Coca](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/). Could "Big Luke" be talking about spoken BrE? because that's where the change begins and where I barely know, if at all.

Comment: @learner Both BNC and COCA contain some speech, and in both cases you can query *only* speech, if you like--click "SPOKEN" on the left-hand side.  When I do so, I find 99 results for *at the weekend* and only 10 results for *on the weekend*.

Comment: That's what I exactly got before you've written your last comment.